# Filter multiple arrays with one condition

Tags: arrays, swift, search, filter, conditional-statements

I have a tableView with different kinds of infos, each coming from a different array.

I could not work with dictionaries because then the list would have been unordered and I could not work with classes, because I have different lists with all kinds of dynamic entries (properties are always different etc.)

Here my problem:
I want to implement a search function. But when I use the filter function for one array, it changes of course based on the implemented condition but the other 5 stay the same => I can't reload the tableView because the array information does not match anymore ...

Here the arrays:

```
var categoryItemUIDs = [String]()
var categoryItemDescriptions = [String]()
var categoryItemLfdNrs = [Int]()
var categoryGivenOuts = [Bool]()
var categoryGivenTos = [String]()
var categoryGivenAts = [String]()
var categoryStorageLocations = [String]()
```

In the tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath method):

```
 cell.customTextLabel?.text = categoryItemLfdNrs[indexPath.row]
 cell.customDetailTextLabel.text = categoryItemDescriptions[indexPath.row]
```

Here the searchBar(textDidChange) method:

```
self.categoryItemDescriptions.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
```

Now I get an array back with reduced size, but all the other arrays stay the same... Is there maybe another way to avoid this problem? I already tried type aliases but it did not work out.

I would appreciate any help!

Kind regards,

Comment: You really should not keep the information in separate arrays, but in a *single array* of a custom struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it goes to such a big count of arrays, the time for your specific type comes.

The simple solution is to create something like

```
struct Category {
  var uid: String
  var description: String
  // ...
  var storageLocation: String
}
```

The you have simply something like

```
var items: [Category]
```

And you can still do simple things in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.customTextLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].lfdnrs
cell.customDetailTextLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].description
```

And only 1 array to filter

```
items.filter { $0.description.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
```

So overall advice is to solve different problem (here I suggested the solution of the *having your data in the app* problem instead of *filtering multiple arrays with one condition*)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var categoryItemUIDs = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
var categoryItemDescriptions = ["ddd","eee","fff"]
var categoryItemLfdNrs = [0,1,2]

struct data {
    var id = ""
    var desc = ""
    var item = 0

    init(id :String, desc:String, item:Int)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc
        self.item = item

    }
}

//var cat = [data]()
//for  i in 0..<categoryItemUIDs.count {
//    cat.append(data(id:categoryItemUIDs[i], desc:categoryItemDescriptions[i],item:categoryItemLfdNrs[i] ))
//}

//more swift
let cat = (0..<categoryItemUIDs.count).map { (i) -> data in
    return data(id:categoryItemUIDs[i], desc:categoryItemDescriptions[i],item:categoryItemLfdNrs[i] )
}


print (cat)

let catFilter = cat.filter { $0.id ==  "aaa" }
print (catFilter)
```